# What was the cloth that Minho and Thomas found in the maze?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

You see in a scene from the **Maze Runner** that when **Thomas** is on his first day as a runner (that first day happens to be the day they find a way out), **Minho** and Thomas had stopped in what Minho called the **Blades**, because they had found a piece of cloth on the ground.

What is the piece of cloth and why is it there? surely it isn't from one of the other runners?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie but I read the book. And yes, the piece of cloth is from one of the previous runners. I don't understand your problem with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloth was of Ben , who was stung by griever one day ago. It is all red from attack of griever.

Answer (score -2):

It's a piece of cloth from one of the previous runners clothing that got ripped to shreds during an encounter with a griever